# Jest Unit Testing in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, jestjs, dockerfile

I am trying to move my tests to my docker image build stage but it seems to ignore my test build at all and just skip it when I build the image.

What can be the problem?

```
# Base build 
FROM node:16.13 AS build
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package*.json ./
RUN npm i -g npm@6.14.15
RUN npm i --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Clean
RUN npm prune --production
RUN npm install -g node-prune
RUN node-prune

# Test
FROM build AS test
RUN npm i -g npm@6.14.15
RUN npm i -D jest typescript
RUN npm i -D ts-jest @types/jest
RUN npm i -D @shelf/jest-mongodb
RUN npx jest

# Release
FROM node:16.13-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist/
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules/
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./
CMD npm start
```

Above you can see my `Dockerfile` where I am preparing the build, then plan to have tests and after that, I am making my release image.

I've already been playing around with that for hours; I cleared cache, made tweaks with the order in the file) but it didn't help. It keeps ignoring my test build.

Any hint of that and in general on my Dockerfile is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker internally has two different systems to build images.  Newer Dockers default to a newer system called [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).  One of the major differences is the way the two systems handle multi-stage builds: the older system just runs all of the build stages until the end, but BuildKit figures out that the final stage `COPY --from=build` but doesn't use anything from the `test` stage, and just skips it.

I wouldn't run these tests in a Dockerfile (since it doesn't produce a runnable artifact) or in Docker at all.  I'd probably run them in my host-based development environment, before building a Docker image:

```sh
# On the host
npm install    # devDependencies include all test dependencies

npm run tests  # locally
# repeat until the tests pass (without involving a container)

# Build the image _after_ the tests pass
docker build -t myapp .
```

`docker build` also has [a `--target` option to name a specific stage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-target-build-stage---target) so you could tell Docker to "build the test image", but you'd just immediately delete it.  This is where I don't think Docker quite makes sense as a test runner.

```sh
docker build -t delete-me --target test
docker build -t my-app .
docker rmi delete-me
```

Your Dockerfile also installs a MongoDB test helper.  If the test depends on a live database rather than a mock implementation, the other thing to be aware of here is that code in a Dockerfile can never connect to other containers.  You have to run this test from somewhere else in this case.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I wanted to move my tests there because I wanted to ensure that code is not broken anywhere before deployment. I usually had my tests in CircleCI. But this time I thought it would be better to make tests in the same environment. I thought it's a widely used practice. But after your comments I can see it's not a good idea. What woudl use suggest me about API testing where you need to have a db?

Comment: For that sort of integration test, you need to run it _after_ you build an image and deploy it to some environment.  Since you're talking only to your process's API, the tests don't specifically need to be launched from a container, or even be in the same language as the server.  My one specific recommendation here would be to make sure you're deploying the image you actually tested; don't build a special test-only image and don't override the image code with a bind mount.

Comment: What if your host system didn't have npm, but did have Docker (or rather, containerd / buildah) ? Then you need to run tests in a build (or separate stage) of some container. Wouldn't the solution just be to change from tag to use the test stage for the final image?